# TypeError: undefined is not an object - Safari & IE

Tags: javascript, iframe, backbone.js, safari

```
runAnimation: function(){
  var iframe = document.querySelector('.active iframe');
  window.frames[iframe.id].contentWindow.runAnimation();
},
```

The above code prints the following error in Safari:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.frames[iframe.id].contentWindow.runAnimation')
```

I have tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718565/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-window-framescontent-do), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711448/iframe-contentwindow-is-undefined-when-use-window-framesname-to-access) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199797/why-is-iframe-contentwindow-null), basically every possible solution.

Another interesting thing to point out is **window** returns **undefined** on Safari only!

```js
/**
 * @property {array} Templates.slide - The template part for each slide
 * Html template for app
 */

//Iframe Template
presenter.Templates.slide = [
  '<iframe id="slide-<%= id %>" class="slide" data-disable-back="<%= disableBack %>" data-disable-forward="<%= disableForward %>" data-position="<%= position %>" data-src="<%= url %>">',
].join('\n');




/**
 * Default options for the carousel.
 * @public
 */

//Owl Carousel options
 Owl.Defaults = {
  ...
  // Classes and Names
  themeClass: 'owl-theme',
  baseClass: 'owl-carousel',
  itemClass: 'owl-item',
  centerClass: 'center',
  activeClass: 'active'
 };

/**
 * The main view for the presentation
 * This renders a collection presentation
 * Builds owlCarousel and attaches api controls
 */
presenter.PresentationView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  
  /**
   * Runs slide animation. Called on the slide itself once its loaded
   */
  runAnimation: function(){
    var iframe = document.querySelector('.active iframe');
    window.frames[iframe.id].contentWindow.runAnimation();
  },
  ...

/**
 * Adds listners for carousel events. Used to trigger runAnimation along with
 * other function
 */
  carouselEvents: function(){
    var self = this;
    this.slider.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(){
      self.showControls();
      self.runAnimation();
    });
  },
  
/**
 * Standard backbone method. Called when view is instantiated
 * @param {object} options - Options passed when creating the view
 *                           (such as instanceURL)
 */
  initialize : function(options){
    this.options = options;
    this.render();
    this.buildSlider();
    this.loadFour();
    this.carouselControls();
    this.carouselEvents();
    this.keyNavigation();
    this.UIEvent();
    this.reScale();
  },

});
```

Comment: you might want to use `document.querySelector(".active iframe")`

Comment: I have tried that already :(

Comment: just tested in IE and seems to be working. can you check the plnkr link i just posted

Comment: Please share the code required to reproduce the problem. We don't even know whether you have an element with an active class or an iframe... and btw, what does this has to do with backbone.js?

Comment: @TJ sorry I'm lost. It doesn't work in Safari & IE. The element exists because it works in Chrome+Firefox, no?

Comment: @Devrim You commented on another answer *"Chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined(…)`"*  maybe that is specific to that answer... Maybe `runAnimation` is not even executing in other browsers..? We need a [mcve] to be sure.

Comment: @TJ Yes, that was specific to that answer. The code above is fine in Chrome+Firefox. I can post more code of course if it helped but I don't think it will. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

i tried like this and it seems to work

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('.container iframe');
window.frames[iframe.id].contentWindow.runAnimation();
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/0pquvlK3beF1pqMcU1lc?p=preview

Comment: Yes, well it should also work in my case but it doesn't work in Safari only.

Comment: any specific version of safari (or OS). working fine for me

Comment: there might be cross origin issue with safari. can you please message all the errors from console

Comment: There is no other error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.frames[iframe.id].contentWindow.runAnimation')
runAnimationapp.js:17689
(anonymous function)app.js:17750
(anonymous function)`